# macOS Cocoa: TabViewController inside Window with Full Size Content View

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, storyboard, macos-sierra

How can I set margin top for **TabViewController** placed inside **Window** that has **Full Size Content View** property set. I am getting such obstructed buttons! 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set a margin. You have to move your objects in the view down. But this is what `Full Size Content View` does. It sets the title bar over the content and gives you a little blurry effect.